# Dynamically generate variables in less loop

Tags: loops, variables, less

I have a series of variables to generate media query variables

```
// declare desired media queries
@mediaqueries: 320, 480, 600, 768, 1024, 1280;
@breakpoints: length(@mediaqueries);
```

I use the above variables to set up grid generation, which works really well.
So if I dropped in another value, the required grid system css would be generated.

Also for speed, I opted to set up a series of variables to quickly output the correct media query conditions.

```
@320-min : ~'screen and (min-width:' unit(extract(@mediaqueries, 1),px) ~')';
@480-min : ~'screen and (min-width:' unit(extract(@mediaqueries, 2),px) ~')';
@600-min : ~'screen and (min-width:' unit(extract(@mediaqueries, 3),px) ~')';
@768-min : ~'screen and (min-width:' unit(extract(@mediaqueries, 4),px) ~')';
@1024-min : ~'screen and (min-width:' unit(extract(@mediaqueries, 5),px) ~')';
@1280-min : ~'screen and (min-width:' unit(extract(@mediaqueries, 6),px) ~')';
```

It works ok, the trouble is if I add new values, remove any of the values in the `@mediaqueries` variable i get errors because of the extract function looking for a set number of values.

This isn;t ideal, as I can't easily drop in or remove unused media query variables.

Is there a way to use a less loop to generate the variables dynamically based on what values are set in the `@mediaqueries` variable?

Something like:

```
.media-query-loop(@breakpoints, @i: 1) when (@i =< @breakpoints) {
  @mediasize: extract(@mediaqueries, @i);  
    @{mediasize}-min : ~'screen and (min-width:' @{mediasize}px ~')';
  }
  .media-query-loop(@breakpoints, (@i + 1));
}
.media-query-loop(@breakpoints);
```

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't generate variables. To be honest the whole approach looks strange. First you create a generic list of values to generate something automatically. Then "for speed" you hardcode the same values in stone. Then you again want to generate a generic list (a set of variables) to replace that stoned list (why do you think "the speed" remains?)...

Comment: I thought that was the case with generating variables. I don;t think I was  clear enough on my idea, I'm trying to avoid hard coding those variables. The concept being that the required media query breakpoints/values are declared in a global variables file. This could then allows me to add in additional breakpoints based on any other devices sizes I felt may need to supported. The hard coded and looped variables are really an idea to see if I can control the number of breakpoints and keep them maintainable.

Comment: Fisrt of all how do you use these `@600-min` variables? Second question is "if a variable is named like `@600-min` can it be anything other then 600px"? - e.g. how do you know what variable you're going to use if the initial list is generic and may not contain any `600` value at all? And finally if you're going to use these variable like [this](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/52378bcf4998386a8c09) why to not use [a generic mixin](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/0d8bd94da875f9cc8dd7) instead?

Comment: Usually it's helpful to give some (minimal) examples of *what* you're trying to solve (instead or in addition to *how* you're trying to solve it (otherwise the chances it's an ["XY problem"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377) are very high)).